# Using Google Chrome Frame as a "closed container" with HandleTopLevelRequests

Tags: google-chrome-frame

Can anyone explain what using GCF as a "closed container" actually means?

I understand from this [link](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started#TOC-Chrome-Frame-as-a-closed-container) that you enable this mode of operation using the HandleTopLevelRequests registry key.

I actually stumbled onto this setting as a way to *prevent* the Developer Tools window from automatically closing upon postbacks/redirects.  That default behavior really makes the Network tab almost useless.  :(

By setting the HandleTopLevelRequests registry key as described in the link above, the Developer Tools window remains open like I want.

I just don't know if this is a setting I should leave in place because I don't really understand what it's doing.

Or I suppose another way to ask it is, why *wouldn't* you want the HandleTopLevelRequests setting in place?

**Another registry key named UseChromeNetworking seems to often be used in conjunction with HandleTopLevelRequests.  Bonus points for any details on it as well.  :)

Any info at all would be appreciated-